# Place holder for date in wpdp::prepare()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for a solution to pass the date placeholder in the `wpdb::prepare()` function.

For example:

```
wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(_id) FROM " . $this->get_table_name() . " WHERE _time=%s AND _date=%d", $time, $date ) );
```

I'm unsure if passing %s for time and %d for a date is the best practice.

PS: `_date` and `_time` columns have the data types of `DATE` and `TIME` respectively

Comment: What type are the columns `_time` and `_date` in the table? The markers must be placed according to the data type of each column. And why didn't you create a single column of type `DATETIME`, there's no point in wasting space having two separate columns when they could be together?

Comment: `_time` is `TIME` and `_date` is  `DATE`

Comment: I assume your database is MySQL. If so, the `date` and `time` types [can be obtained from strings or from integers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html), it all depends on what you are receiving and therefore what controls you have set when the user provides that data.

Comment: Thanks, WordPress primarily runs on MySQL database. I will try your solution and see if all goes well